# Object detection with ionic

Tags: object, ionic-framework, mobile, camera, detection

i want to use object detection to detect obstacles in the road with the phone camera using ionic, please doese any of you have examples related to this topic;
I appreciate a lot whatever the gesture to help me
thanks in advance. :hugs:

Comment: You question needs more clarification of what you want to achieve, maybe images or example of specific app, etc...

Comment: @Mostafa Harb i'm using a mobile app with ionic to detect object in the road using camera of the phone,so i want to know what kind of model i will use,is it possible to deploy my detection model in mobile?some of peaple proposed me tensorflow js as library to build my model in the phone,but i didn't find any exemple of this,if yous have any suggestion please help me,thank you!